# How to make a Menu of Snippets with the Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I have managed to get my snippets working with the basic autocompletion:

```
ace.define("ace/snippets/bosun",["require","exports","module"], function(require, exports, module) {

exports.snippets = [
    /* Sections */
    {
        name: "alert definition",
        tabTrigger: "alertdef",
        content: 
"alert ${1:alertname} {\n\
    warn =\n\
}\n"
    },
    {
        name: "template def",
        tabTrigger: "templatedef",
        content: 
"template ${1:templatename} {\n\
    subject =\n\
}\n"
    },

    /* Funcs */
    {
        name: "avg reduction function",
        tabTrigger: "avg",
        content: "avg(${1:seriesSet})"
    }
]

exports.scope = "bosun";

});
```

In the documentation on snippets it says:

> When triggering a snippet through a menu or command you can configure
>   it to use the text selected prior to inserting the snippet in the
>   resulting code.

But I'm not clear on how I would create menu to list the snippets? (Ideally a menu that has submenus for each category of snippets, but happy to crawl first...)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone has a better way. But from reading the code in https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/snippets.js I have come up with:

```
$scope.aceLoaded = function (_editor) {
    editor = _editor;
    $scope.editor = editor;
    editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
    editor.focus();
    editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
    $scope.snippetManager = ace.require("ace/snippets").snippetManager;
    $scope.bosunSnippets = $scope.snippetManager.snippetNameMap["bosun"];
    editor.on("blur", function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.items = parseItems();
        });
    });
};

$scope.listSnippets = function() {
    var snips = $scope.snippetManager.snippetNameMap["bosun"];
    if (snips) {
        return Object.keys(snips)
    }
    return {};
}

$scope.insertSnippet = function(snippetName) {
    $scope.snippetManager.insertSnippetForSelection($scope.editor, $scope.snippetManager.snippetNameMap["bosun"][snippetName].content);
    $scope.editor.focus();
    $scope.editor.tabstopManager.tabNext()
}
```

Which seems to work, perhaps there is a better way.